# I want to store my firestore value as boolean but it is being stored as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form in reactjs when i submit it it stores value in firestore database. I have a status feild where users can choose true or false, my problem is this option gets submitted as a string, i want it to get it is submitted as a boolean. Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Code :

```
const [masterMenu, setMasterMenu] = useState([])
const [form, setForm] = useState({

status: "",

})
const masterMenuCollectionRef = collection(db, "masterMenu")
setForm({
  status: "",
}).then(() => { 
  
 })}
 }
 <div className='outer-container'>
  <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold py-2'>MASTER MENU</h1>
  <label style={{marginLeft: "0.3cm"}}><b>Status</b></label>
      <br />
        <select style={{marginLeft: "0.3cm", marginBottom: "20px", borderBottom: "2px solid 
 #006400", paddingBottom: "10px", width: "38cm"}}
          onChange={e => setForm({ ...form, status: (e.target.valueAsBoolean) })}>
          <option value="">Select Status</option>
          <option value="True">True</option>
          <option value="False">False</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: You have to provide a javascript boolean value to the Firestore SDK, not the string value that you are now.  Firestore won't convert it for you - you have to do that in your code as needed.  Form fields are all strings by default, and so is the empty string "".

Comment: can you tell me how to do that

Comment: Maybe Google can.  Have you tried searching for "javascript convert string to boolean"?

Comment: yes, but i am getting confused i am actually fairly new to react and i need this urgently so if possible can you share how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`option` doesn't accept boolean type of data but there are many ways to convert string into boolean but the most simplest way is to assign the value of **`True`** as **`1`** and **`False`** as **`0`**. See example snippet below:

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  console.log("Selected option is " + $('#mySelect').val());
  console.log(Boolean(parseInt($('#mySelect').val())))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option disabled selected>Select Status</option>
  <option value=1>True</option>
  <option value=0>False</option>
</select>
```

In the example above, I converted the option value into `int` by using `parseInt` and then converting it into Boolean Type. You could also apply this logic into your code and it's up to you how you will implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.parse` to convert it from string to boolean type.

```js
console.log(typeof JSON.parse("false"))
console.log(typeof JSON.parse("true"))
```